# SPA: Can I use both Angular.js and Ember.js?

Tags: angularjs, ember.js

I am very wary of using an all-inclusive application framework for building my SPA.  I have done a lot of reading on the subject, but I haven't found any articles on whether these frameworks are composable or not.  I have a long-held architectural belief that frameworks should not try to do too much, rather they should:

1. do one thing only
2. do it very well
3. easily compose with other frameworks

Having said this, I'm trying to think outside the "should I use Angular, Ember, or Backbone" box and ask if there is a way to use more than one.  For example, would it be possible to use Angular's templating (which I've heard is awesome) but use also Ember's routing (which supposedly rocks)?

My goal is to make the "all-important SPA framework decision" less important, so that I can change it later.  If we go with a mixed approach, it buys us 2 major benefits:

1. we can rip out the "templating" engine or the "routing" engine or the "whatever" engine individually, and thus not need an entire application re-write to change something we don't like
2. by figuring out how to make them play nice together, we would be able to switch out *individual* routes/controllers/views allowing use to switch frameworks/approaches in small granular steps

Would this be a reasonable choice or totally fraught with annoying difficulties?

If the answer is the latter, then these frameworks are fundamentally flawed and I will not be using them.

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to combine both. Read this Quora thread which might interest you : http://www.quora.com/Client-side-MVC/Is-Angular-js-or-Ember-js-the-better-choice-for-Javascript-frameworks

Comment: If you *have* to combine both it's probably easiest to run an Ember app inside an Angular app by specifying the `rootElement` for the Ember app to run inside.

Answer (score 1):

The innards of both Angular and Ember are tightly coupled.  You could do portions of a page with just Ember or just Angular, but mixing the routing/templating/data-binding from one framework to another would be an extremely difficult task.

Comment: Thank you.  That seems like a poor way to construct a framework.  I don't see why they don't play well together.  "If you can't play nice, then you can't play at all" IMO.

Comment: It's a difficult task to design a framework and make it both user friendly for developers, and super fast.  Most often this requires taking advantage of intimate knowledge of the related processes.  It's great when things are modular, but it doesn't always lend itself to the best product.